# Returning deck of cards based on user input for player and cards per player in java

Tags: java

I have the deck of card shuffling and returning results but now i want to alter the output based on the user input: Number of players and the number of cards per player.

**Original code:**

**CardRun - main**

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Deck deck = new Deck();
    Card C;

    System.out.println(deck.getTotalCards());
    System.out.print("Number of players: ");
    int players = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Number of cards: ");
    int cards = scan.nextInt();

    while(deck.getTotalCards() != players)
    {
        C = deck.drawFromDeck();
        System.out.println(C.toString());
    }

}
```

**Deck Class**

```
public class Deck {
private ArrayList<Card>cards;

Deck()
{
    cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
    for(int a=0; a<=3; a++)
    {
        for(int b=0; b<=12; b++)
        {
            cards.add(drawFromDeck());
        }
        cards.addAll(cards);
    }
}

public Card drawFromDeck()
{
    Random generator = new Random();
    int index = generator.nextInt(cards.size());
    return cards.remove(index);
}

public int getTotalCards()
{
    return cards.size();
}

}
```

**Card Class**

```
public class Card {
private int card, suit;
private static String[] suits = {"Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"};
private static String[] cards = {"Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};

Card(int suit, int card)
{
    this.card = card;
    this.suit = suit;
}

public @Override String toString()
{
    for(int i = 0; i<players; ++i)
    {
        System.out.println("Player " + (i+1) + ": "+ cards.get(i));
    }
}

public int getCard()
{
    return card;
}

public int getSuit()
{
    return suit;
}
}
```

**Output**
Deck of cards: 54
Number of players: 4 (entered by user)
Number of cards per user: 5 (entered by user)
Player 1: Ace of Spades, 2 of Hearts, Red Joker
Player 2: 8 of Hearts, 10 of Clubs, 9 of Hearts
Player 1 has the better hand.

Comment: Please be more specific on what the output should look like at the end of the day :)

Comment: @poitroae added desired output format. Thanks for your help ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see, you let every player draw `cards` cards from the deck:

```
List<Hand> hands = new ArrayList<Hand>(players); // defines each players hand (in your case one, each "cards" cards);

// let 'em draw
for(int k=0; k<players; ++k) {
    Hand currentHand = new Hand();
    for(int i=0; i<cards; ++i) {
       currentHand.add(deck.drawFromDeck());
    }
    hands.add(currentHand);
}

// find the best
Collections.sort(hands); // make sure to implement Comparable, to reasonably check which one has the best hand

for(int i=0; i<players; ++i) {
    System.out.println("Player " + (i+1) + ": " + hands.get(i)); // Make sure Hand::toString() is overriden properly
}
```

Yep, I think that should do it and it still is perfectly **clean and modular**.

Comment: Will each player doesn't just get 3 cards the user decides the number of player and cards in the input from using scanner. but i will go ahead and apply what you have provided and see how it goes

Comment: @Amina yep that's just one more parameter, no problem with this design. **I edited it**.

Comment: So does this mean that i will have to convert my current usage of an array into an arrayList? Also i am adding these changes to the deck class.

Comment: Yep, using an ArrayList  makes it easier after all.

Comment: ok.. so i updated my code above with what you have provided me and if possible take another look.. my head is not fuller wrapped and as i am working it over if you can point out anything wrong please do. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Amina Where are the for-loops, where `Collections.sort()`? By the way, please upvote the question, if it helped you in some way.

Comment: the for-loops are in the deck class Deck() and as for the `Collections.sort()` using random doesn't it do the same thing or in this case the collections sort is preferred?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25919/discussion-between-amina-and-poitroae)